# VS Code debugger Failed to load message bundle for file ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools-2.1.2\out\extension

Tags: vscode-debugger

When I debug my JS script the debug console gives me this error:

> Failed to load message bundle for file c:\Users\ganuo.vscode\extensions\ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools-2.1.2\out\extension

I also open a new window that I don't know what it's for. Do you know what happens?

[image]